# System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser login dialog doesn't appear

Tags: webbrowser-control, windows-authentication

When I navigate to an intranet site requiring windows authentication, the WinForms WebBrowser control isn't displaying a login dialog.  But it will display (after refreshing the page) if I first open Internet Explorer and view the same page.

Also, if I make the URL refer to my local IIS instance, the login dialog will appear.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can send credentials via IAuthenticate. You can either [extend the winform webbrowser site](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/ExtendedWebBrowser.aspx) or [write your own webbrowser wrapper](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/csEXWB.aspx).

Comment: Yeah, I saw these articles on these techniques.  Thanks.  But it seems like the log-in dialog should at least be displaying without the inducement of first browsing the page in IE.  I suppose that this behavior is a bug; but I'm not really sure.